# iv characteristic graph confusion

Tags: batteries, graph

I am trying to understand how a iv graph for a battery rated at 10V with internal resistance of 10 Ohms would look like. I was thinking it would just be a constant 10V for the graph, however, I am unsure how internal the internal resistance would impact the terminal voltage.

Comment: Hint: what will be the effect of the internal resistance if you connect a load that draws non-zero current?

Comment: The concept of "internal resistance" for a battery is a ***model***. It's a simple model. The reality is a ***lot*** more complex. But it's a usable, 1st order approximation. Think about it the model, itself. How is it composed? Probably as an "ideal voltage source" and a series resistance, with the modeled battery terminals including both. Now just think about what happens as current is supplied by the ideal source through the internal series resistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frAJBS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The 10 V battery can be modelled as an ideal 10 V source with a 10 Ω series resistance.*

- With no load connected the output voltage will be 10 V. This is marked with an 'X' on the upper left of the VI graph.
- If we short circuit the battery - seldom a good idea with real batteries - we will have 10 V across R1 and \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {10}{10} = 1\ \text A \$. This also is marked.

Now you should be able to fill in the rest of the points. Calculate the voltage drop across R1 at 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 and 0.8 A and plot the resulting terminal voltage on the chart.

Comment: You put in the work to illustrate the approach in a way that I think the OP will understand well. (Or should be able to.) It's also had the work involved in keeping it clean and to the point. Nice.